# How to plot multiple rows on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, categories

Say I have the following `pandas` dataframe:

```
In[114]: df
Out[114]: 
     0-10%  11-20%  21-30%  31-40%  41-50%  51-60%  61-70%  71-80%  81-90%  \
f    0.186   3.268   3.793   4.554   6.421   6.345   7.383   8.476   8.968   
l    1.752   2.205   2.508   2.866   3.132   3.157   3.724   4.073   4.905   

     91-100%  
f     12.447  
l      8.522
```

and say I want to produce a barplot where I have the columns as categories on the x axis and, for each category, two bars, one for `f` and one for `l`, so to make comparisons.

**How to do this in order to avoid the bars being stacked?**

My attempt produces stacked bars and an offset in terms of x labels:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
labels = ['0-10%','11-20%','21-30%','31-40%','41-50%','51-60%','61-70%','71-80%','81-90%','91-100%']
row1 = df.iloc[0]
row1.plot(kind='bar',title='Binned comparison', color='r',stacked=False)
row2 = df.iloc[1]
row2.plot(kind='bar',title='Binned comparison', color='k',stacked=False)
plt.xticks(x,labels, rotation='horizontal',fontsize=8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `plot.bar` on the transpose:

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do you access the colors of the bars and the orientation of the x labels?

Comment: @CF84 orientation I don't know off the top of my head.  Colors, try: `df.T.plot.bar(color=['red', 'aqua'])
`